# How to show the activity of user1 on user2's feed without any follow relation between them?

Tags: getstream-io

I have a scenario where i want the users of my application to get a 'new user in your area' activity in their feed. As far as i know user2 will only get user1's activity in his feed only if user2 follows user1.

If the user1 has just made his account on my app there doesn't exist any relationship between user1 and user2.

Hence, i want to know if i can add user1's activity in user2 feed without user2 following user1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [notification feeds](https://getstream.io/notification-feeds/) suit your needs? It allows you to notify user2 of user1's activities.